# how to remove some strings in emeditor(Regex )

Tags: regex, emeditor

i want to remove some string and save other part of string that i need from a file with emeditor ..

file line like :

```
{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"user_flags\":2143,\"id\":702212125,\"access_hash\":\"914250561826\",\"first_name\":\"david\",\"last_name\":\"jones\",\"username\":\"david_d192\",\"phone\":\"051863329875\",\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusRecently\"}}","phone":"051863329875","version":"3","type":"unknown","token":"1556189892619764206","p_id":702212125,"username":"david_d192","type":"redis","user_flags":2143,"host":"win",from":"contacts"}
{"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_id": "36GG54F"}}

{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"user_flags\":2143,\"id\":702212125,\"access_hash\":\"914250561826\",\"first_name\":\"david\",\"last_name\":\"jones\",\"username\":\"david_d192\",\"phone\":\"051863329875\",\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusRecently\"}}","phone":"051863329875","version":"3","type":"unknown","token":"1556189892619764206","p_id":702212125,"username":"david_d192","type":"redis","user_flags":2143,"host":"win",from":"contacts"}
{"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_id": "36GG54F"}}

{"message":"{\"_\":\"user\",\"pFlags\":{\"contact\":true},\"user_flags\":2143,\"id\":702212125,\"access_hash\":\"914250561826\",\"first_name\":\"david\",\"last_name\":\"jones\",\"phone\":\"051863329875\",\"status\":{\"_\":\"userStatusRecently\"}}","phone":"051863329875","version":"3","type":"unknown","token":"1556189892619764206","p_id":702212125,"type":"redis","user_flags":2143,"host":"win",from":"contacts"}
{"index": {"_type": "_doc", "_id": "36GG54F"}}
```

i want to save id, first_name , last_name , phone , username(if exist) in every line =>

```
id:702212125 first_name:david last_name:jones phone:051863329875 username:david_d192,
id:702212125 first_name:david last_name:jones phone:051863329875 username:david_d192,
id:702212125 first_name:david last_name:jones phone:051863329875,
```

how i can do this ?

thanks

Comment: This is not a job for regex.  This is a job for JSON.  https://www.emeditor.com/emeditor-core/emeditor-v15-9-0-supports-json/

Answer (score 1):

JSON parsing is the optimal way to do this (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-parse-data-from-json-into-python). But you can make life harder and use regex (here presented in PCRE (PHP) flavor):

Get all id's:

```
(?<=id\":\s\")(\w+)(?=\")
```

See example:
https://regex101.com/r/g5vfEd/1

Get all first names:

```
(?<=first_name\\\":\\\")(\w)+(?=\\)
```

See example:
https://regex101.com/r/g5vfEd/2

Get all last names:

```
(?<=last_name\\\":\\\")(\w)+(?=\\)
```

See example:
https://regex101.com/r/g5vfEd/3

Get all phone numbers:

```
(?<=phone\\\":\\\")(\w)+(?=\\)
```

See example:
https://regex101.com/r/g5vfEd/4

Get all user names if they exist:

```
(?<=username\\\":\\\")(\w)+(?=\\)
```

See example:
https://regex101.com/r/g5vfEd/5

complete pattern to match everything:

```
id\\?\":\s?\"?(\w+),?[\\\"].*first_name\\\":\\"(\w+).*last_name\\\":\\\"(\w+).*phone\":\"(\d+).*(?=username)?\":\"(\w+).*
```

Returns 3 matches, each with the following 5 groups (here match 1 is shown):

```
Group 1.    85-94   702212125
Group 2.    145-150 david
Group 3.    169-174 jones
Group 4.    285-297 051863329875
Group 5.    454-462 contacts
```

See link: https://regex101.com/r/g5vfEd/6

Comment: thanks . at the complete pattern  usename not found ,  can i want you to put the python source to find from file and save result in a new file  data is more than 100k lines? x_x

Comment: You can do something like `res = re.findall(regex, text)`, and then `for m in res:  print(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5))`

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged regex and Emeditor you can try this.

Emeditor version  19.1 onwards supports regex named groups like this:

```
(?<id>expression)
```

and named backreference by using this form:

```
\k<id>
```

So steps:

Find and Replace (Ctrl-H). Tick "Match Case" and select "Regular Expressions".

Find:

```
\\"id\\"[\\":]*(?<id>[^\\":,]*).*?\\"first_name\\"[\\":]*(?<first_name>[^\\":,]*).*?\\"last_name\\"[\\":]*(?<last_name>[^\\":,]*).*?\\"phone\\"[\\":]*(?<phone>[^\\":,]*)(.*?"username"[\\":]*(?<username>[^\\":,]*))?
```

Replace with:

```
id:\k<id>\tfirst_name:\k<first_name>\tlast_name:\k<last_name>\tphone:\k<phone>\tusername:\k<username>
```

Click the down Arrow next to the Extract button and select "To New Document"
Click the Extract button to output to a new tab delimited file.